# CORS preflight call not firing the following GET/POST request

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

In the WebAPI application I have the Custom CORS policy implemented as described in the article: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#allowed-origins but the origins are set in the `web.config` file in the custom section. And I have the angular client application that sends the requests to the WebAPI one.

I tried two scenarios:

1) Run the application using the `localhost` url.

2) Run the application using the computer name.

In both the cases I have the origins included in the `web.config` file. In first case everything works fine. In the second the CORS preflight requests are sent, but there is no actual GET or POST request following. In the preflight response there are the correct headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type, custom-session-id
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://computername
```

What can be wrong? I would appreciate any help.

Edit: screenshot from the fiddler:

[image]

Comment: the `OPTIONS` has to return `200 OK` for the preflight to continue, also check the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` if it's working it means your configuration for computername is wrong

Comment: I get the 200 status. I tried the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` - but the problem exists. I had the `AllowAnyMethod` set to true and `AllowAnyOrigin` as well. But no luck.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of actual Request and response headers for the `OPTIONS` call?

Comment: `app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);` this MUST be executed first on top of other settings, check the order in your Startup.cs

Comment: @Sherlock: You mean the `config.EnableCors();` call? Should it be called also before the route mapping and adding the custom message handler?

Comment: @owczarek yes, im using web api 2.0 bdway maybe there is a difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution: there was a missing setting in the `CorsPolicy` object: `SupportsCredentials` needed to be set. I have not expected that even if I do not send the credentials I still need to set this flag.